# How do I convert from MFC's COleDateTime to C# DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, mfc, coledatetime

I have an older library that uses COleDateTime as a return type in a C++ MFC Dll.  When I do a PInvoke, can I marshal that with confidence to a DateTime object?  Or should I do something wacky, like convert the COleDateTime into the number of ticks since 1970, and then convert those ticks back to a DateTime object in the C# calling project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return a double, by accessing the [`m_dt` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3yyz5xk.aspx) on the [`COleDateTime` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx).

Then, you would pass that double to the static [`FromOADate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) on the [`DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) to convert the double to a `DateTime` instance.

Answer (score 4):

Use DateTime.FromOADate().